# Home network (modem, switch, RJ45 wall socket, TV) no internet?

Tags: networking, router, internet, switch, cat6

I would like to ask for your help. Here I created a basic image of my home network setup:

[image: my home network setup]

ISP Modem/router--)RJ45 wall socket--)switch--)TV  = no internet on TV

ISP modem/router--)Switch--)RJ45 wall socket--)TV = TV connects to internet

The problem is I really need the switch to be after the RJ45 wall socket as I would like to connect multiple devices to the internet through the switch.
All cables are CAT6 and the wall socket has been correctly wired for CAT6.
What's the problem?

Please help me with the troubleshooting.

Comment: Check that the cable is not wired for crossover or something weird when going to the wall socket. If the TV supported auto crossover but the switch did not it could cause setup 1 to fail but setup 2 to work.

Comment: Did you make these wires yourself? Did you wire the jack yourself? What [wiring standard](http://www.omnisecu.com/basic-networking/tia-eia-568-standards.php) did you follow? Most likely, the mapping of pins to pairs is off.

Comment: Thanks both of your fast responses. My switch is TP-Link TL-SG105, with Auto MDI / MDIX on every port. All cables are standard CAT6 patch cables bought in a PC store. The only thing I did is cutting off 1 jack of the ethernet cable that goes from the modem to the wall socket. I did the wiring myself following this picture: [link] (http://graph.darren-criss.org/2016/03/08/rj45-wall-jack-wiring-diagram-l-fa709cf4477a441b.gif)

Comment: If you used Category-6 cable, you wasted money. I seriously doubt you have the ability to wire Category-6 and have it pass the Category-6 test suite, especially if you need to ask this question. Did you use a Category-6 wall jack? If not you don't have a Category-6 system. Did you use a wall jack that is made for stranded cable? Most are for solid-core cable, which you are supposed to use behind the wall (horizontal cable), and it will probably fail at some inopportune moment.

Comment: Ron: the wall socket is CAT6 compatible, this is the exact model I have: [link] (http://www.digitus.info/en/products/network-infrastructure/wall-outlets-lsa-connection/cat-6/dn-9006-n/). The cable I used is a solid cable. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I tested another scenarios eliminating the switch: modem--)wall socket--)tv  = no internet again. So the only working scenario is modem--)switch--)wall socket--)tv. Hope it helps in the investigation.